# Getting the parent id of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, identifier

I have troubles to get the parent id of  elements.

```
$(function(){
$("#elem-132224").append("<button class='sum'>+</button><button>-</button>")
$(".sum").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

why is not working?

Comment: Its' because you haven't assigned any id to the `buttons` with class `sum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because the button doesn't have an `id`. It merely has `class`. You can write it like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#elem-132224").append("<button id='my-id-123' class='sum'>+</button><button>-</button>");
  $(".sum").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

If you want to get the parent `id` (the element which `<button>` is inside it), you can use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) in jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $("#elem-132224").append("<button class='sum'>+</button><button>-</button>");
  $(".sum").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Watch your double quotes there

Comment: Yes i need the parent id. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are not adding `id` attributes in the button html.

Change

```
$("#elem-132224").append("<button class='sum'>+</button><button>-</button>")
```

To

```
$("#elem-132224").append("<button class='sum' id='someid'>+</button><button>-</button>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your element doesn't have an ID, so (unsurprisingly) you can't display it.

Note that there's no need to call jQuery again to obtain the ID (once you've assigned one). It's a property of the element itself which is passed as `this` to event handlers:

```
$('.sum').click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
})
```

or if you want to get the parent's ID - `this.parentNode.id`